# How to display data in angularjs from 2 join tables in codeigniter?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I need to fetch user_id, firstname, lastname from user table and feedback_id,comment,user_id and recipe_id from feedback table where user_id from user is equal to the user_id in user table.

Review.html

```
  <div class="items item item-avatar" ng-repeat="comment in feedbackdata">
  <img src="img/asd.jpg">
  <h2>{{comment.firstname}} {{comment.lastname}}</h2>// I don't know what to put here
  <p>{{comment.feedback_id}}</p>
  <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
  <p>{{comment.user_id}}</p>
  <p>{{comment.recipe_id}}</p>
```

Controller.js

```
   .controller('CommentCtrl', function($scope, CommentList,$state,$location,SessionService,getFeedbackService) {

   $scope.userdata = SessionService.getObject('userdata');
   $scope.newComment={};
   $scope.newComment.userID =  $scope.userdata.user_id;

   getFeedbackService.all().then(function(payload) {
   $scope.feedbackdata = payload.data;
   console.log(payload);
   });

  $scope.addComment = function(){
  CommentList.add($scope.newComment);
  console.log($scope.newComment);
  };

  })
```

Service.js

```
.factory('getFeedbackService', function($http){

return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.get("http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_feedback_data");
    }
 };
 });
```

main.php

```
    public function get_feedback_data()
{
    $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $feedback = $this->User_model->feedback_data();
    echo json_encode($feedback);
}
```

user_model.php

```
    public function feedback_data()
    {


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('feedback')
    $this->db->join('user','user.user_id = feedback.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to display feedback_id,user_id, firstname, lastname and comment in angular js?

Comment: But that's not an actionable question. We have no idea what part of this works or doesn't work. Outline what you have done to troubleshoot

Comment: I tried displaying data from one table only and it works. I don't know what to do when I'm going to fetch and display data from two joined tables..

Comment: i need to figure out how to bind the data to from two joined tables

Comment: for a start ... add a sample of the data output to question. Assuming it is outputting properly. By the time it gets to angular.....shouldn't need to think of it as joined tables....just an array of objects

Comment: I'll try this one ..thank you.